# Can solidity Smart Contract written in higher version interact with another deployed smart contract written in older version?

Tags: solidity

Does it work? is there any gotcha that we need to watch out for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely no issue for new contracts to interact with contracts which are already deployed for long time *( which suggests that they are probably older solidity versions )*. Recently I deployed a contract with solidity version `7.0.0` and inside of it I created a instance of already existing contract ( by interface contract ) which is running on solidity `0.4.8` and the newer contract is passing and reading data from the old contract without any issues.

Comment: Nice! would you be able to share the link to your deployed contract?